# Sliding divs right to left using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a website in which I have multiple pages. I want them not be a different webpage but to be a different div on the same page. Then I have two left and right buttons on which it, when a user clicks a particular div, should slide left or right according to the arrow. How can I do this with jQuery, HTML, CSS?

My Divs:

```
<div id="main-page">    
</div>
<div id="about-us">
</div>
<div id="contact-us">
</div>
```

The Divs have a particular background-image, and their size is full-screen.

My script:

```
$("#main-page").click(function() {
    $("#main-page").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
    $("#about-us").show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
});
```

As I said, I don't want to do like that. I want arrows to check what div has the turn to slide left or right.

Comment: I want to slide the divs right to left!

Comment: That's a statement, not a question.

Comment: How can i slide the divs right to left?

Comment: [`jQuery.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is what you want in order to achieve a sliding animation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12446983/1250044

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="next" value="Next">
<input type="button" class="prev" value="Prev">
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1500px
}

.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: thin solid red;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    display: inline-block
}

​.prev,
.next { position: fixed; top: 50% }

.prev { left: 0 }
.next { right: 0 }
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    // We create an array and populate
    // it with all .box left offsets
    var boxLefts = [];
    $('.box').each(function(i, el) {
        boxLefts.push(this.offsetLeft);
    });

    // Now we attach an on click event handler
    // to our prev/next buttons
    $(".prev, .next").click(function(e) {
        var dir = false,
            targetLeft = -1;

        // to get the current direction
        // we use the className of the current clicked button
        var target = e.target.className;

        // we set the earlier defined direction variable
        // based on the clicked button
        if (target == 'next') {
            dir = 1;
        } else {
            dir = -1;
        }

        // when the next-button is clicked
        // we loop through the .box-offsets array
        if (dir) {
            // prevent the default onclick behaviour
            e.preventDefault();

            // get the current scroll-offset
            winLeft = window.scrollX;

            $.each(boxLefts, function(i, v) {
                // we check that we are not at the end or beginning
                // of the viewport. If we are not
                // we set targetLeft to the current/matching offsets-array item.
                if ((dir == 1 && winLeft < v && targetLeft < 0) || (dir == -1 && winLeft > v)) {
                    targetLeft = v;
                }
            });

            // if truthy we animate the scrolling to the next/previous box-offset
            if (!targetLeft) {
                $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').stop().animate({
                    scrollLeft: targetLeft
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        // prevent the default onclick behaviour
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/s2TJQ/4/)

Comment: One more request. Can you give me the explanation. :) I will be really thankful to you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='all-pages'>
        <div class='page' id='page-1'>PAGE 1</div>
        <div class='page' id='page-2'>PAGE 2</div>
        <div class='page' id='page-3'>PAGE 3</div>
        <div class='page' id='page-4'>PAGE 4</div>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
   width: 960px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

.all-pages {
   float:left;
   width: 10000px;
   position: relative;
   left: 0;
   top:0;
}

.page {
   float: left;
   width: 960px;
}
```

In essence, it is the same principle as jCarousel, except you are basing the positioning and widths of the elements on a larger scale so each item fills the page:

- `container` - The viewable area
- `all-pages` - effectively a 'reel' of all the pages

Next, you need to add left and right buttons to the page (or a menu?) to scroll the display. These will have to be positioned absolutely so it stays within the container view.

When you add functions for the left and right buttons, you just use a jQuery animate style function to change the value of left within the all-pages div, which will create a smooth looking transition.

Comment: can you tell me the script to write as well?